# Do you only export your own modules in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to **Node.js**, and I am not clear over the **module.exports**, as I understand you only export your own modules (those you code) and not the **built in** or the **installable node-modules**? Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 0):

Should you require module "A", which in turn, requires module "B", you would only need to export functions from "B" if module "A" requires it's direct usage. Any module that "B" requires, must be required within "B" and does not need to be required in module "A".

You can however, export any function from any module directly from your own module but is not necessary if you can require the module later in the code that requires it's direct usage.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a project that requires very specific filesystem behavior, so you decide to write a custom library to give you functions that behave in the particular way you want them to (we'll call it `my-fs`). You're going to import `fs` into your custom library and then build your system on that. Now let's imagine that, in addition to your custom features, you really just need `fs.readFileSync` to do what it already does. You have two options. The first is to import `fs` and `my-fs` in your project and use `fs.readFileSync` with `myFs.everythingElse`. *Or* you could have `my-fs` export `fs.readFileSync` and just import `my-fs` as `fs`, which will result in cleaner code for your finished project.

So there can certainly be good reasons to export code you didn't write.